# Unable to preview component when title is modified and not saved

Tags: 2013-sp1, component

I am receiving an error when modifying component title and previewing without saving changes.

**Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your question with detailed error. Also ensure that you'r previewing in the right publication.

Also check does your component have any external items like images from other systems.

Comment: The error pops up saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". The error comes in all publications and for all components. Preview works well if component title is not modified or modified and saved.

Comment: can you check event viewer logs and check preview path in cme config  clean the directory and try

Comment: Cleaned up directories but didn't work, Also the issue occurs in all environments. Seems an issue with Tridion.

Comment: Did you check the event logs, and try to check for such issue any hotfix was released by sdl tridion

Comment: I second the call to check the event logs, as that will give you the full error including the stacktrace. Look for warnings from ASP.NET in the Application log, in addition to any errors in the Tridion log.

Comment: Sorry, I missed to update here. We were using external image items using Bynder which was causing issue. Thanks for all your suggestions.